# How can I give a user the permissions to run "adduser" and "deluser"?

Tags: docker, alpine-linux, sudoers

How can I give a user the necessary permissions so that he can run "adduser" and "deluser" - but no other privileges?

```
FROM alpine:3.15.4

RUN addgroup -S tgroup -g 12345 && adduser -S tester -G tgroup -u 23456
RUN chown tester:tgroup /home &&  chmod 0700 /home
RUN adduser tester wheel

USER tester
WORKDIR /home/tester

# just for testing purpose
RUN addgroup -S ssh && adduser -S newuser -G ssh
```

Do other packages have to be installed for this?

Currently I get the error message:

```
---> Running in 31db4ea578ed
addgroup: permission denied (are you root?)
```

Comment: This doesn't really seem like a programming question and [unix.se] might be a better place to ask.  Since `adduser` needs to write to the encrypted password file `/etc/shadow`, anyone with enough permissions to run it could also reset any user's password, including root's.

Comment: if you are talking inside the container then you can make groups with specific provilege in Docker but if you are talking about alpine then well David Maze gived you the best hint i think